# How can I ensure that my web pages are not modified by end customer?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, security

I want to lock down my website so that the end customer cannot change the standard web pages(aspx). I have investigated code signing and digital certificates. But that is more suited for the dlls and executables, and not to the aspx/html pages themselves. Is this possible? If so, please provide me some links.

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Are you selling your site for your customer to install on their network?  Or just putting it out there for people to use?

Comment: I am selling my site for the customer to install on their network, so that their employees can use the site. But I do not want them to modify the pages.

Answer (score 6):

You can precompile your ASP.NET application.

"When you precompile an ASP.NET Web site for deployment you create a layout containing assemblies and other information that you can then copy to a production server. A Web site that is precompiled for deployment gives you the ability to create a compiled version of the site that can be deployed to a production server without source code."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into providing your application as Software as a Service (Saas)?